# Struts 2 Validation using Message Store Interceptor

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts-validation, struts2-interceptors

I have an action where I am trying to log the user in.

```
public class RegisteredUserAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
..
..
 public String login() throws Exception {

        DBLogic dBLogic = new DBLogic();
        RegisteredUser user = null;
        try {
            user = dBLogic.getRegisteredUser(getUserUsername(), getUserPassword());
        } catch (CredentialException e) {
            addFieldError("userUsername", e.getMessage());

            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return INPUT;
        }

        if (user != null) {
            session.put("user", user);
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the username or password is invalid, I throw a CredentialException and then populate that exceptions message in my fieldError. I even tried adding an Action Error.

With some advice and searching online, I managed to use the Message Store Interceptor using annotations in the RegisteredUserAction.action and the MainAction.action respectively storing and fetching.

```
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.InterceptorRef;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.InterceptorRefs;
@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef(value = "store", params = {"operationMode", "STORE"}),
    @InterceptorRef("defaultStack"),})
```

AND

```
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.InterceptorRefs;

@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef(value = "store", params = {"operationMode", "RETRIEVE"}),
    @InterceptorRef("defaultStack"),})
```

This is the struts.xml file contents that are relevant:

```xml
<package name="pages" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <global-results>
            <result name="displayPage">/WEB-INF/template/page.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/WEB-INF/template/page.jsp</result>
        </global-results>
        <action name="registrationPage" class="actions.MainAction" 
              method="loadRegistrationPage"></action>
        <action name="loginPage" class="actions.MainAction" 
              method="loadLoginPage"></action>
</package>

<package name="operations" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <action  name="userLogin" class="actions.RegisteredUserAction" method="login">
            <result type="redirect" name="input">loginPage.action</result>
            <result type="redirect" name="success">homePage.action</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

I am using a template based approach wherein the Middle content(in my case the LoginPage.jsp) is included into the mainpage dynamically.

My page.jsp (which includes the mainContent):

```xml
<s:include value="../%{mainContent}.jsp" ></s:include>
```

My login.jsp (which gets included):

```xml
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<s:form action="userLogin" method="POST">
    <s:textfield name="userUsername" />Error:<s:fielderror name="userUsername" />
    <s:password name="userPassword" />
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

The redirect works properly and the login form appears, but no errors.
I've even tried using the Message Store interceptor in the struts.xml with no luck. :(

Comment: If you are using `convention plugin` why are you still using xml?

Comment: Where did you put `@InterceptorRefs` annotations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `redirectAction` result instead of `redirect`. And try using configuration in `struts.xml` file instead of annotations.

```xml
<action name="userLogin" class="actions.RegisteredUserAction" method="login">
   <interceptor-ref name="store">
      <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
   </interceptor-ref>
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
   <result type="redirectAction" name="input">loginPage</result>
   <result type="redirectAction" name="success">homePage</result>
</action>
```

Comment: can you explain, why `redirectAction`

Comment: Why plain redirect? From Struts2 documentation about "Redirect Action Result" `It is strongly recommended that if you are redirecting to another action, you use this result rather than the standard redirect result.`